# Reflection GetExecutingAssembly is throwing a StackOverflow

Tags: .net, exception, reflection

I'm trying to get the path of the currently executing assembly using reflection to use in registering some types. This is being called in a static/shared method

```
Dim Path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location
```

This line throws a StackOverflow exception with the following details:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.StackOverflowException
    Data:            unable to evaluate expression.
    HelpLink:        unable to evaluate expression.
    HResult:         unable to evaluate expression.
    InnerException:  unable to evaluate expression.
    Message:         unable to evaluate expression.
    Source:          unable to evaluate expression.
    StackTrace:      unable to evaluate expression.
    TargetSite:      unable to evaluate expression.
```

The call is being made on the main thread. I'm using .Net 4.5/VS11 Beta

For the record, `GetEntryAssembly`, `GetCallingAssembly`, etc... all do the same. I've never seen (or even read about) this behavior before - does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

OS: Win7 x64 Ultimate
It's a Winforms application

I've got a shared method which should return a dependency resolver (wrapped in my own class to abstract it).

```
Private Shared _Resolver As IDependencyResolver
Public Shared Function QuickResolver() As IDependencyResolver
    If _Resolver Is Nothing Then
        Dim Container = New WindsorContainer
        ''Line below was breaking so I exploded it into multiple lines as shown above
        Dim CurrentPathFilter = New AssemblyFilter(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location))

        Container.Register(
            Component.For(Of Interfaces.ISomeInterface)().
            ImplementedBy(Of DAL.SomeType).LifestylePerThread)

        ''.... More registrations ....

        Dim Resolver As New WindsorDependencyResolver(Container)
        _Resolver = Resolver
    End If
    Return _Resolver
End Function
```

It's singleton-ish (I know the initialisation should be refactored into a different method - it's on my list)

It's being called as follows from the Winforms UI thread:

```
    Resolver = Common.DependencyResolverFactory.QuickResolver
    ScanRepository = Resolver.Resolve(Of IRepository(Of Scan))()
```

The exception is being thrown by the `GetExecutingAssembly` line (that's where exception breaks) I admit it's unusual so am assuming it's that my code is bringing it close to a SO and the GetExecutingAssembly method nests deeply enough to overflow?

Comment: How you're sure that overflow is in that line not your own code at another line?

Comment: Can you show us some context of this line of code? what other things does the method do?

Comment: On which OS you are trying this code.

Comment: is that a WinForms app ? And you are calling this from application assembly not from some class library assembly ? Please clarify

Comment: Dynamic Assembly are not supported to get location.

Comment: @Romil I hadn't considered that but in this case, It's a standard assembly. Nice point though

Comment: I would guess your Resolver is being called to resolve the Assemblies. Put a break point on a line before the `GetExecutingAssembly` line to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use following sample code to get the assembly directory.

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
```

or

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Foo).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName)
```

Comment: Wow... Nothing like using a line that already appears in the Q as the answer... `IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)` - See line 6 of the full example. That said, I'm starting to think the `GetExecutingAssembly` is a red herring - most likely the call nests a bit and that nesting is just enough to max out the stack after something else has already _almost_ filled it

Comment: It seems that you are able to get path but "new AssemblyFilter()" at line 6 is causing the error. please split this statement in two line. First get the path and then pass this path in AssemblyFilter constructor.

Comment: Thanks for answering but if you look at the first snippet, putting `Dim Path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location` on a line on its own still throws the exception - I'd already split it away from the constructor in case that was the problem...

Comment: No I haven't - but I need to understand why this is throwing an exception. It's also worth noting that the second option requires a type which is possibly problematic since the purpose of this class is to register all types in assemblies in a given directory (at least, all those signed by me) so it's got to be able to handle assemblies for which I don't yet know any types.